# Using the Tensorflow Dataset map function to retrieve multiple sentences for a single image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I am trying to implement the Neural Image Caption generator with visual attention proposed in the "Show, Attend and Tell" paper. For validation, I want to compute the Bleu score. For this, I need to get all the captions for a particular image. I thought of approaching the problem as shown below:

```
data_path = './processed_data'
split_type = 'val'
encoded_captions = np.load(data_path + '/{}/captions_{}.npy'.format(split_type, split_type))
image_paths = json.load(open(data_path + '/{}/img_paths_{}.json'.format(split_type, split_type), 'r'))

encoded_captions, image_paths = shuffle(encoded_captions, image_paths, random_state=0)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, encoded_captions))

dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_path, cap: map_func(img_path, cap, image_paths, encoded_captions))

def map_func(img_path, caption, image_paths, encoded_captions):
    matching_captions = [caption for i, caption in enumerate(encoded_captions) if image_paths[i] == img_path]
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (299, 299))
    img = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(img)

    return img, caption, matching_captions
```

When running the above code, I am getting the following error:

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

How do I resolve this issue? Alternatively, is there a more efficient way of getting captions that map to a particular image?

Thank you very much!

Comment: did you try decorating the function with `@tf.function`?

Comment: Doing the following fixed the problem:

`dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: tf.numpy_function(map_func, [x, y, image_paths, encoded_captions], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32]), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)`

However, I think i might go in for a dictionary. It seems much easier and faster as well. Furthermore, the above method breaks when the number of matching captions are different.